# Flask resets the connection with redirect + render_template via POST method, depending on the request size

Tags: python, flask

I get an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error when many records are sent to the client (via flask.render_template) after a flask.redirect.
If I do not perform a flask.redirect (direct call of the function that returns the render_template), there is no connection reset, regardless of the size of the request.

The following example resets the connection with Chromium and randomly with Firefox (with number_records >= 500).

I use Python 3.10.9, Flask 2.0.3, Chromium 107.0.5304.121 and Firefox 108.0.1

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, redirect, url_for

# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET depends on number_records
number_records = 100    # no error observed
number_records = 500
number_records = 1000

# data used in templates
choices = ["choice_1", "choice_2", "choice_3"]
dn = {}
for i in range(1, number_records+1):
    dn[i] = "name_%d" %(i)

# flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    tmpl1 = """
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>Test main</title></head>
  <body>
    <hr>
    <form method=POST action=manage_names>
      <h1>Select the names</h1>
      <table id="t_names">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for k, v in dn.items() %}
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="{{ k }}" checked></input>
            </td>
            <td>{{ v }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
      <br>
      </table>
      <br>
      <button type=submit name=submit-button value=submit method=POST>submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
"""
    return render_template_string(tmpl1, dn=dn)

@app.route("/manage_names", methods=["POST"])
def _manage_names():
    # no code for tests
    return redirect(url_for("_set_choices"), code=307)

@app.route("/set_choices", methods=["POST"])
def _set_choices():
    tmpl2 = """
<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head><title>Test ERR_CONNECTION_RESET</title></head>
  <body>
    <hr>
    <form method=POST action=manage_choices><h1>Set the choices</h1>
      <table id="t_choices" class="choice">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>choice</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for k, v in dn.items() %}
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ v }}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ k }}"/>
              <select name="choice" id="{{ k }}">
                {% for c in choices %}
                <option>{{ c }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
      </table>
      <br>
    <button type=submit name=submit-button value=submit method=POST>submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
"""
    return render_template_string(tmpl2, dn=dn, choices=choices)

@app.route("/manage_choices", methods=["POST"])
def _manage_choices():
    # For tests
    return redirect("/")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error occurs when the connection is unexpectedly closed by the server. This can happen if there are network issues, server overload, or timeouts.

In your case, I think the issue is related to the size of the response being sent back to the client direct after the redirect.

you can try to allow Flask to send larger responses without resetting the connection with this code:

```
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024  # 16 MB
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing `app.run(debug=True)` with this:

```py
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO(app)
socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```